# Change TimeZone in 'UTC' postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, timezone

What is the difference? between below 2 approaches for time zone change in the UTC

1. change_tz(gbc.actual_date_time, 'UTC', tz.time_zone)
2. change_tz(gbc.actual_date_time, 'UTC' :: CHARACTER VARYING,tz.time_zone)

In the 2nd approach, I have used CHARACTER VARYING so what is the exact difference and which one is better

Comment: What database are you asking about? Title says `postgres`, but you tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:postgresql]. Doesn't matter too much, because neither have the `change_tz()` function you're asking about, so the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

In [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';
```